# Deploy Angular 8 Universal (SSR) application on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal

I recently upgraded my Angular 8 application to be an Universal application (SSR). I had it deployed to Firebase before it was a SSR application, but then I figured out that deploying a SSR application on Firebase doesn't work by using regular Firebase Hosting. I did some research and discovered that I have to use [*Firebase Cloud Functions*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

I created a SSR application using:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject PROJECT_NAME
```

*`PROJECT_NAME` can be found in `angular.json` file below `"projects"` section.*

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Important note**: This solution was taken from Q&A section of the Angular course on Udemy ([here](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2)). I tried it out and with some modifications managed to make it work.

---

So, first make sure SSR actually works by running `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`.

Then install Firebase Tools and initialize the project:

- If you didn't install the Firebase Command Line Tools already before, run `npm install -g firebase-tools`
- Run `firebase login`, providing your Firebase credentials (email/password) if requested.
- Run `firebase init`

Answer some questions ...

- "Are you ready to proceed?"

  Type `y` and hit ENTER.
- "Which firebase CLI features do you want to setup?"

  Choose ...

  ```
  (*) Functions

  (*) Hosting
  ```

  ... , selecting both with the SPACE key, and hitting ENTER.
- "Select a default Firebase project for this directory?"

  Select one with the ARROW keys and hit ENTER.
- "What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions?"

  Select `TypeScript` with the ARROW keys and hit ENTER.
- "Do you want to use TSLint?"

  Type `y` and hit ENTER.
- "Do you want to install dependencies with npm now?"

  Type `y` and hit ENTER.
- "What do you want to use as your public directory?"

  Type `dist/browser` and hit ENTER (Please note: this is different from deploying an app without Universal!).
- "Configure as a single page app?"

  Type `y` and hit ENTER.
- File index.html already exists. Overwrite?

  Type `n` (important!) and hit ENTER.

Modify some files ...

- In **firebase.json** replace `"destination": "/index.html"` by `"function": "ssr"`

  (`ssr` points to this `export const ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);` variable, you will find it below).
- In **server.ts** add `export` to the `app` initialization: `export const app = express();` instead of `const app = express();`
- In **server.ts** either comment out the last three lines (`app.listen(...)`) or replace them with these:

```js
    // If we're not in the Cloud Functions environment, spin up a Node server
    if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME) {
        // Start up the Node server
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
        });
    }
```

You can remove them when deploying to Firebase but you need them when running `npm run serve:ssr` to be able to host your app on `localhost`.

- In **webpack.server.config.js** modify the `output` like this:

```js
    output: {
        // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        // Export a UMD of the webpacked server.ts & dependencies for rendering in Cloud Functions
        library: 'app',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
```

and modify `externals` like this:

```js
    externals: [
        // Firebase has some troubles being webpacked when it's in the Node environment, so we will skip it.
        /^firebase/
    ],
```

This will *fix* an error:

> Cannot find module 'require("./server/main")'

when running `npm run serve:ssr` or `firebase serve` commands.

- Rebuild your app by running `npm run build:ssr`.
- Using the terminal move to the functions folder: `cd functions`
- Install a npm package for filesystem access: `npm i fs-extra`
- Inside the **functions** folder create a new file named **copy-angular-app.js**, with this content:

```
    const fs = require('fs-extra');
    fs.copy('../dist', './dist').then(() => {
        // We should remove the original "index.html" since Firebase will use it when SSR is enabled (instead of calling SSR functions),
        // and because of that, SSR won't work for the initial page.
        fs.remove('../dist/browser/index.html').catch(e => console.error('REMOVE ERROR: ', e));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('COPY ERROR: ', err)
    });
```

This *fixes* initial page not loaded as a SSR (instead of showing content for the initial page it's still showing `<app-root></app-root>`).

***Note:*** Since we removed `index.html` file, running `npm run serve:ssr` won't work unless you first rebuild your app (by running `npm run build:ssr` -> this will recreate `index.html` file).

- In **functions/package.json** (not in the project's package.json!) change the build entry like this:

`"build": "node copy-angular-app && tsc",`

- In **functions/src/index.ts** replace the content with this:

```
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

    const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server`).app;
    export const ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

- In the terminal make sure that you are in the **functions** directory, and there run `npm run build` to copy the `dist` folder into the `functions` folder.

***Additional note:*** To make building for Firebase easier you can create a script in the main project's `package.json` file:

```
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server", // this one should already exist
    "build:ssr-firebase": "npm run build:ssr && npm --prefix functions/ run build",
```

This script will first build your Angular SSR application (`npm run build:ssr`) and then it will run `npm run build` inside your **functions** folder (that way it will copy the project's `dist` folder to your **functions** `dist` folder and will remove the project's `index.html` file).

Deploy your app ...

- You can serve your app locally before deployment, on **localhost:5000**, by running `firebase serve` (if you want).
- Stop the server (Ctrl + C).
- Then you can deploy the app by running `firebase deploy` and visit it via the url which is displayed in the terminal.

This way I managed to deploy my Angular SSR app on Firebase.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It was so much fun of an adventure. Thank you !!

Comment: After Firebase Deploy completes. Meta tags and alternate links generated dynamically are not reflecting on firebase link. But it is working in firebase serve

Comment: Will this overwrite/delete my exisiting firebase functions?

Comment: This will only create/update a function named _ssr_ for your specific project once it is deployed. It won't touch functions you defined in other projects.

Comment: Is that the usual behaviour of Firebase function deployment?

Comment: I am getting this error on deployment after following your asnwer: https://imgur.com/a/rQhzncu

Comment: I wish there was a way to upvote multiple times. You sir saved me from a huge headache.

Comment: Isn't functions a bad choice? Functions frequently do cold starts and are slow to respond. They also don't work outside the US

Comment: There is no webpack.server.config.js file

Comment: Great course by Max, @miselking we've done the same self-study :)

Comment: Perfect answer that helps me a lot especially in the copy angular app script

Answer (score 2):

Basically fantastic answer by @miselking, I just wanted to add that `Angular` now is (`Angular 9` and above) using CLI Builders to build & serve SSR apps, therefore the `webpack.server.config.js` is no longer needed, in my case it even didn't work at all after upgrade from `Angular 8`. The issue [#16348](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16348) explains the way how external dependencies are now managed, if needed to add. In `angular.json` now you can add `externalDependencies` and that's the kind of replacement for `webpack`'s custom configuration related to `externals`/`nodeExternals`.

Other than that, the answer by @miselking is still up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Firebase just came out with a [new simple way](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md) to deploy it with **ng deploy**! I think they are still working out the bugs though...