# SSR firebase function error during deployment

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an Angular 12 app, with Angular-Universal for SSR (Server-side Rendering) using Node 10. I am trying to run `ng deploy`. It used to work fine. Now I get the following error:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        ssr(us-central1)
```

When running `firebase deploy --only "functions:ssr" --debug` I get the following error message:

```
[2021-11-13T23:49:01.906Z] Error: Failed to update function ssr in region us-central1
    at C:\Users\theoh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:38:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (C:\Users\theoh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:250:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (C:\Users\theoh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:134:13)
    at async handle (C:\Users\theoh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:75:17)
```

On the firebase console, the logs of the ssr function include the following error:

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: module__default.default.createRequire is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14250:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.22306 (/workspace/dist/bbc/server/main.js:1:5423600)
    at __webpack_require__ (/workspace/dist/bbc/server/main.js:1:7247455)
```

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you provide your minimal Firebase function code snippet which produces this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to `angular.json` the Node Version of 12, with the line `"functionsNodeVersion": 12` solved my issue:

```
   "deploy": {
      "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
      "options": {
        "functionsNodeVersion": 12,
        "ssr": true
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be a version issue. Can you upgrade to the latest version of node.js and see whether the issue persists or not. For More details you can refer to the [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447459/15774176) where miselking has outlined the deployment steps and Daniel added the [latest input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559886/15774176) in the previous answer.

Comment: @chadoulis is that answer helped?